# What can this pin on my keyboard connector be?

Tags: usb, identification, keyboard

I'm trying to place a USB-C connector on my keyboard so I can use a removable cable with it. It's a Ozone Strike Pro with audio and USB pass through. I managed to map 10 of the pins with a multimeter between the cable and the connector ends, the first 6 are for audio and 4 are for USB. But I can' figure out what that last brown wire is.

It's not connected to the USB housing or the audio plugs shielding. The only other place I can think of is the USB inner shielding, which I don't have access to without chopping the cable. Could that be it? If so, where should I plug it, considering the USB-C female boards I have seen only have 4 solder pads, connect it directly to ground?

[image]

Comment: Can you make out what that pin is connected to on the PCB?

Comment: @brhans I tried following the traces, but got lost. The ones in the edge are hard to see

Comment: Use the continuity feature of a multimeter to see if it's connected to ground? Pierce the cable ínsulation slightly to see if it's connected to the shield? Usb shield is supposed to be connected only on one side sometimes so it may make sense that it's not tied to the casing of the male end. And if you are replacing it, go big or go home, cut the cable or plug housing up to figure it out.

Comment: Why a USB-C port?  Would not a USB-B port be easier?  If size of the standard B port is a problem then mini and micro ports are an option.  Plugging a USB-B device into a USB-C port only needs the right kind of cable, and they are easy to find.

Answer (score 0):

If your keyboard is USB-C, it might be the configuration channel.
.
.

[image: usb-c configuration channel negotiation]

Comment: It's USB-A, I'm trying to add USB-C